# Will I get more pests/insects if my neighbor sprays and I don't?

Tags: pest-control

Had a pest control company come by today. To be honest this is about the 5th one, and I am tired of them trying to sell me their services. In all actuality we don't have that many pests/bugs.

They tried to sell me today on the fact that they are spraying homes on both sides of me, and because of that, I will probably see a huge increase in the number of bugs if I don't spray. I'm not worried, I can spray myself. But I prefer not to because we have an organic vegetable/fruit garden in our backyard.

Their logic makes some sense, but at the same time it doesn't. Does spraying kill the bugs that are currently there, or does it drive them away? Will I really see an increase in bugs? If I spray what should I spray with that is organic?

Comment: Hemmed in on two sides by a no fly zone, I'd think you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pests (and all living things I suppose) tend to populate their environment to capacity.  If any action drives them to seek new territory, and that territory is already at capacity, then any population spike will only be temporary.  Population dynamics is a complex topic and no real-world system is inherently stable or predictable, so take this with a grain of salt.  But I'm pretty sure the pest control company is just giving you a sales pitch.

As for "orgainic" sprays, you'll have to be specific about the type of bug you are spraying for.

Comment: The only bugs we really get are spiders (non harmful) and midges. I rarely see ants, and don't really see anything else.

Comment: @esac Sounds like your only pests are homo sapiens. Ask a neighbor for one of their "Sprayed By" signs and stick it in your lawn. That will take care of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just depends on a persons tolerance level. Some people will see a single American or Smokey Brown roach and they are on the phone to their pest control person. If an occasional bug every now and then does not bother you (an occasional bug seen is normal) than don't worry about having your place treated. I only treat my own place once a year and I've been doing pest control for 23 years now. Do I see an occasional bug that's not welcome, yes. But I don't go and start spraying down the house.

We need the bugs for our environment for us to survive. We only have a problem when there is an infestation. But to some people, one bug is an infestation. Have your house treated once every couple of years or when and if you have a problem would be my recommendation. A good pest control professional can spot problems well before the home owner. I try my best to talk anyone out of frequent or quarterly pest control. I some areas, quarterly pest control is needed. If that's what they want, that's what I give them.

If you have any termites, Carpenter Ants, Fire Ants, Bed Bugs, or rodents in a structure, you should use a professional, or at least consult with a couple.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My neighbors got sprayed a couple days ago.  I keep my yard natural.  It is a bird sanctuary.  I've always had some bugs but the last two days have been horrible!  I was outside for maybe ten minutes yesterday and fifteen today.  I have four nasty spider bites on my neck and two on my face.  Bugs in my face everywhere.  Intolerable.
So my answer is yes.  They do move into your yard where they can breathe clean air and have clean food.  Ugh!

Comment: On the bright side, there's now more food for more birds, too,.